# SharePoint 2019 ON PREMISE - How to create managed property

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, managed-metadata, managed-property

I am not sure on the flow of how to go about making a searchable managed property.

I need to create a property that allows numbering sequence to enable a user to set the priority (1-1000) on news items.

Currently there is not enough choice under the highlighted content.
I need an A-Z on how to do this and enable it the managed content to be mapped / crawled.
Help always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is list column, please refer to the following steps:

1. Create a list column and fill in values, then a crawled property
   available with the name ows_ColumnName will be generated.
2. Create a managed property of Text type, select Searchable,Queryable
   or other required properties, then add a mapping between crawled
   property and managed property.
3. Run a full crawl to check the result.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-search-schema#to-add-a-managed-property

If the property is site column, you just need to fill data and run full crawl since SharePoint will automatically created crawled and managed properties for site column which contains value.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/from-site-column-to-managed-propertywhat-s-up-with-that

Comment: Don’t need to do a full crawl, just re-index the list/site.

Comment: Thanks Julie -that connects the dots for me.

Comment: Thanks Greg - much appreciated.